# sql, outer join

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have two tables, linked with an outer join. The relationship between the primary and secondary table is a 1 to [0..n].  The secondary table includes a timestamp column indicating when the record was added.   I only want to retrieve the *most recent record of the secondary table for each row in the primary*.   I have to use a group by on the primary table due to other tables also part of the SELECT.  There's no way to use a 'having' clause though since this secondary table is not part of the group.

How can I do this without doing multiple queries?

Comment: can you give the full structure, as well as whatever query you have now that's not working?

Comment: You should definitely give us your query, or at least a skeleton of it, so we get a better idea of what you're actually saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT a.id, b.* 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.parentid = a.id
WHERE b.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table2 c WHERE c.parentid = a.id)
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you want to show rows for IDs in table1 without any matches in table2.

Comment: I think you mean `MAX(timestamp)`, to get the latest one.

Comment: With with the "select(max...)" as part of the WHERE clause this won't work with an outer join (the result is that it will return *only* the rows from table a which also have at least one row in table b.
However, I think this is close.  I add an 'or b.timestamp=null' to the where clause and it seems to work.

Comment: @Steve Lopez: point taken. For a `LEFT JOIN`, you'd have to change the outer `WHERE` to an `AND` so that the subquery gets applied in the join condition; this way, even if the subquery doesn't yield any rows, the outer join will still produce results for these cases.

Answer (score 3):

For performance, try to touch the table least times

Option 1, OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT *
FROM
   table1 a
  OUTER APPY
  (SELECT TOP 1 TimeStamp FROM table2 b
   WHERE a.somekey = b.somekey ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) x
```

Option 2, Aggregate

```
SELECT *
FROM
  table1 a
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) AS maxTs, somekey FROM table2
   GROUP BY somekey) x ON a.somekey = x.somekey
```

Note: each table is mentioned once, no correlated subqueries

Comment: @declan: Most of them, especially the 2nd one

Comment: I think he means "Which RDBMS?"  The answer is "MS SQL".  I don't know of any other RDBMS that uses APPLY.  [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sql-s-apply-operator.aspx) is a nice discussion.  [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) are the MS docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1 left outer join table2 a on
   table1.id = a.table1_id
where
  not exists (select 1 from table2 b where a.table1_id = b.table1_id and b.timestamp > a.timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I know of is this:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  B.SomeField
FROM
  Table1 A
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      B1.A_ID,
      B1.SomeField
    FROM
      Table2 B1
      LEFT JOIN Table2 B2 ON (B1.A_ID=B2.A_ID) AND (B1.TimeStmp < B2.TimeStmp)
    WHERE
      B2.A_ID IS NULL
  ) B ON B.A_ID = A.ID
```

Comment: This isn't quickest with the triangular JOIN on table2 at all.

Comment: Well, this is the quickest way that _I_ know of, or at least for a result that includes a field from the second table.